# Getting thread name from NtQueryInformationThread

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to get thread name by ID, like this:

[image]

C Code:

```c
NTSTATUS PhGetThreadName(
    _In_ HANDLE ThreadHandle,
    _Out_ PPH_STRING *ThreadName
    )
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PTHREAD_NAME_INFORMATION buffer;
    ULONG bufferSize;
    ULONG returnLength;

    bufferSize = 0x100;
    buffer = PhAllocate(bufferSize);

    status = NtQueryInformationThread(
        ThreadHandle,
        ThreadNameInformation,
        buffer,
        bufferSize,
        &returnLength
        );

    if (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    {
        PhFree(buffer);
        bufferSize = returnLength;
        buffer = PhAllocate(bufferSize);

        status = NtQueryInformationThread(
            ThreadHandle,
            ThreadNameInformation,
            buffer,
            bufferSize,
            &returnLength
            );
    }

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        *ThreadName = PhCreateStringFromUnicodeString(&buffer->ThreadName);
    }

    PhFree(buffer);

    return status;
}
```

I want to implement this in C++ code.

Comment: That C code will work in C++. Just replace `PhAllocate()`/`PhFree()` with something more appropriate, like `new BYTE[]`/`delete[]`, or `std::vector<BYTE>`, etc

Comment: That being said, have a look at [`GetThreadDescription()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreaddescription)

Comment: believe me i tried but it needs a lot of fixing, maybe i don't have the skill to fix it

Comment: i also tried to use GetThreadDescription() but it gives me some hex values like this
https://i.imgur.com/nfA5e8i.png

Comment: here's the code:
https://pastebin.com/raw/sG6fv6Vr

Comment: "*i also tried to use GetThreadDescription() but it gives me some hex values*" - `GetThreadDescription()` outputs a pointer to a null-terminated `wchar_t` string (`PWSTR` is an alias for `wchar_t*`). `std::cout` does not support printing a `wchar_t*` pointer as text, so it prints it as a `void*` pointer instead, ie it prints the memory address the pointer is pointing to. Use `std::wcout` instead to print it as text.

Comment: i just logged in to tell you that it worked ! thank you sooooooo much dude u saved my life, i feel so stupid now, thanks again !